# Javascript "Don´t change states to fast"

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling, toggle, eventhandler

Hey guys i have an code which changes from one state to another when you click on a button(it starts a video and blends). Now i try to say my eventhandler if someone clicks very fast he shouldnt use it as input. Something like = Eventhandler please notice just oneclick in one sec. Hope this is understanble here my code :

```
<script>
    var clickState = 0;
    var btn = document.querySelector('#playbutton');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if (clickState == 0) {
    document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_1');

    var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

    videoEl_1.play();
    document.querySelector( "#skyid" ).emit('fade_1');
    clickState = 1;

    } else {

    document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_2');

    var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

    videoEl_1.pause();
    document.querySelector( "#skyid" ).emit('fade_2');
    clickState = 0;
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the button when it is clicked and then set a timeout to reenable it after a second.

Like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        // disable the button
        $("#myButton").prop("disabled", true);

        //do the things you want the button to do:
        console.log("doing stuff");

        // reenable the button after 1 second
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#myButton").prop("disabled", false);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/20n1gb89/8/

I've used some jQuery here, but setTimeout is native JavaScript

edit:

It seems you are defining a click handler inside a click handler for the same button. See my comments. Remove the btn.addEventListener and just keep the if else statement. See if that works.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // here you define a click handler for playbutton
        $("#playbutton").click(function () {
            // disable the button
            $("#playbutton").prop("disabled", true);

            //do the things you want the button to do:
            var clickState = 0;
            var btn = document.querySelector('#playbutton');

            // here you define a click handler for the same button 
            // inside the first click handler. You shouldn't do that.
            btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                if (clickState == 0) {
                    document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_1');

                    var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

                    videoEl_1.play();
                    document.querySelector("#skyid").emit('fade_1');
                    clickState = 1;
                } else {
                    document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_2');

                    var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

                    videoEl_1.pause();
                    document.querySelector("#skyid").emit('fade_2');
                    clickState = 0;
                }

                console.log("doing stuff");

                // reenable the button after 1 second
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#playbutton").prop("disabled", false);
                }, 2000);
            });

        });
    });
```

edit 2:

That is. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#playbutton").click(function () {
        // disable the button
        $("#playbutton").prop("disabled", true);

        //do the things you want the button to do:

        var clickState = 0;

        // this doesn't really make sense. clickState will always be 0 
        // as it is defined as 0 each time you click the button. You 
        // will need to define clickState outside the click handler 
        // for this to work.
        if (clickState == 0) {
            document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_1');

            var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

            videoEl_1.play();
            document.querySelector("#skyid").emit('fade_1');
            clickState = 1;
        } else {
           document.querySelector('#toggler').emit('fade_2');

            var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#video');

            videoEl_1.pause();
            document.querySelector("#skyid").emit('fade_2');
            clickState = 0;
        }

        console.log("doing stuff");

        // reenable the button after 1 second
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#playbutton").prop("disabled", false);
        }, 2000);
    });

});
```

});

Comment: hmm i tried insert my code in `doing stuff* but it want work properly some idea?

Comment: no errors it seems like it works a bit. you cant press fast but also the first click dosnt get noticed and sometimes it still can get clicked before the timeout ends

Comment: it works but not constantly its a bit confusing its like when you press 5 times or something it jumps thx fpr the help im ok with this result i dont think somebody presses this 5times really fast in a row

Comment: now everythings fine :) maybe i just needed to delete cache or something thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add an eventlistener on click and creating a timer with it

for example, here after the user clicks the button, we launch a 1000ms timer, if the button is clicked within this time-interval, we will display an alert.

```
 var btn = document.querySelector('#playbutton');
 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
             if (btn.clicked == true){
                  alert("Cmon dude, chill a little");
             }
       }, 1000);
 });
```